# What is the time complexity of the Java code below

Tags: java, data-structures, time-complexity

It's a simple java code to find a total number of the distinct triplet in an array whose sum is divisible by a targetNum. The code works fine but I need to make sure its time complexity is not more than O(n^2).

```
public static void main(String [] args){

    int totalNum = 10;
    int targetNum = 5;
    int inputArray[] = { 1,10,4,3,2,5,0,1,9,5 };


    HashMap<Integer,int[]> tempMap = new HashMap<>();
    int tempCount=1;
    for(int i=0; i<totalNum-2; i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j<totalNum; j++){

            int num1 = inputArray[i];
            int num2 = inputArray[j];
            int [] tempArr = new int[2];
            tempArr[0] = num1+num2;
            tempArr[1] = j;
            tempMap.put(tempCount,tempArr);
            tempCount++;
        }
    }
    int finalCount=0;
    for(int i=1; i<tempCount; i++){
        int [] tempArr = tempMap.get(i);
        int val1 = tempArr[0];
        int startIndex = tempArr[1]+1;

        for(int j=startIndex; j<totalNum; j++){
            int val2 = inputArray[j];
            if((val1+val2)%targetNum == 0){
                finalCount++;
            }
        }

    }
    System.out.print(finalCount);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The time-complexity of the posted code is O(n^3).

The first loop is O(n^2): it's a nested loop, where the range of both loops is proportional to O(n).

The second loop is O(n^3): although it looks much like the first one (one loop nested in another), the range of the outer loop is proportional to O(n^2), and the inner loop to O(n). That gives a total O(n^3).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I need to bring it down to n^2,

Comment: @RohanJain, try solving this task for 2 numbers in O(n), it will be easier to see the approach and then extend it to your case.

Comment: This is the actual question:
 a trio of numbers is special if their sum is divisible by a mythical constant M  find out how many distinct triplets of numbers have their sum divisible by M. Unfortunately, this problem is hard for him to crack and he needs your help Input Take two integers as input, N and M, representing the number of integers in the sequence and the mythical constant respectively. Next, take N integers as input (duplicate integers are allowed).The output should contain only one integer, the number of distinct triplets which have their sum divisible by M